# Is it possible to have a break in the purfling in an instrument of the violin family?

Tags: violin

I was only able to see the purfling from a photo and saw a break in the violin purfling, as in the picture below. From the wood grain across the purfling it does not seem that the purfling is drawn. Is it possible that a real purfling is broken up in this way?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your basic question, yes; purfling is an inlay of multiple strips of wood, so it could be damaged. This photo is too blurry to tell anything, though. (Maybe it's Bigfoot!)

I'm concerned that all your posts have been about minor cosmetic concerns and appear not to have access to the instruments themselves, only photos. I wonder whether, instead of asking out of personal curiosity, you're trying to build some sort of app that does something like assess instruments via photos and AI?

This would be ill-advised, and so would any attempt to draw conclusions about an instrument that you're not holding. The best way to assess a mark on an instrument is to take it to a knowledgeable luthier. They've been practicing their craft for centuries, and even if an AI could be trained to the point of the Singularity and be able to assess visual anomalies with the same insight, a trained luthier has a lot more skills at their disposal than visual inspection. They can look around and inside the instrument, they can take it apart if need be, they can tap it and poke it and most of all play it and see how it responds.

Please don't try to assess an instrument through photographs alone.

Comment: Insightful advice. :)