# Is it severely problematic if the edge of a violin break off?

Tags: violin

If a part of the violin outside the purfling breaks off, would it be some other adverse effect besides the aesthetic ones? Would the structural stability of the violin be adversely impacted?

[image]

Comment: This needs the  addition of   "asking for a friend"  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Disclaimer: [Again](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/125947/78419), if you have this instrument in your hands, take it to a luthier; don't trust the advice of people on the internet who have nothing to go on but the picture. If you *don't* have the violin in your hands, then you're one of those people, and should not dispense advice to the person who took the picture.)

But since you're asking in the abstract, I'll give an abstracted (and largely useless) answer:

**Maybe.**

It's conceivable that a bit of the edge of the top plate could chip off with no impact to the structural integrity (aside from the fact that that area is now slightly more vulnerable). I guess this is why the top and bottom plates *do* stick out beyond the ribs (unlike guitars); it provides some measure of protection. (So why don't guitars do it? Tradition, I guess?)

At the same time, it's quite likely that any accident that caused this damage could also damage more integral parts, perhaps in unseen ways. In this photo, the damage is right at the neck. Is the neck joint loosened? Is the block, inside the body, compromised? Did the impact cause damage elsewhere? These can't be determined from this photo at this angle.

Comment: A guitar usually does not have a carved top, I suppose thus overhanging sides would look a bit weird. Also due to the different playing posture it would be rather uncomfortable to have these plates stick out over the sides. Also a guitar uses some sort of bracing inside along the edges to give more stability.

Answer (score 1):

Of all the little bumps and bruises a string instrument can experience, this is relatively innocuous.

Of course, if it's of the quality of a "good student instrument" or better, then you would want to have it repaired, when you have it in the shop for some more major reason.

If you can find the little piece that chipped off, you can glue it on with Elmer's glue.  This would be most successful if you found some way of immobilizing and putting a bit of pressure on it.  I think that the standard vise would probably not work well.  Therefore, what I would do, if it's a reasonably valuable instrument, is put the little piece in an envelope, maybe airmail, or make a little envelope out of thin paper, and stow the envelope, folded up, in the little box in the case where you keep your rosin.  (Label the envelope.)

If the little piece disappeared, that's okay.

If this is a school instrument, you may safely confess to your teacher (with the instrument available for inspection -- otherwise you'd be scaring the person unnecessarily).  If the teacher goes ballistic, there's something wrong with them.

All that said, please do check whether the instrument ended up "open" at that spot.  Unlikely, but if so, there could be a bit of a buzz while playing, and if this bothers you, then you could ask your teacher to show you how to slip some Elmer's glue into the space with a piece of paper, and use a padded vise during drying.  (Don't overtighten.)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, the edge of the violin has a strip of ebony (technically a compound strip) inlayed, thus I suppose it could be possible for a part of the edge to chip off if the glue does not hold well in that part. Unless you’ve had some specific accident something like this could happen even from a small problem during construction.

As long as there is not hole in the corpus at that space this should not affect the sound noticeably. A violin maker will be able to fix this up a bit aesthetically.

If the chip is big enough that there is a hole this will affect sound, again a violin make should be able to fix such a thing to some extent, as long as the instrument is worth the investment.

If the violin is of any worth you should take is to a violin maker every now and then, to make sure that the glue joints are closed and the varnish on the neck is okay. On such an occasion you might get this checked as well.

Comment: My understanding is that the purfling is "inset" into the top plate, and doesn't go all the way through it. So the loss of the edge of the top plate wouldn't be a failure of glue, but an actual break in wood. And since the OP asked about damage "outside the purfling," it's hard to imagine this damage opening a "hole" to the interior, behind the rib...

Comment: @AndyBonner Of course it doesn’t go all the way through. This is done by carving a ridge and gluing in a bent strip of wood. Nevertheless carving a ridge will structurally weaken the wood in that part, so if the strip is not glued well this is part that might break off more easily.